# Adding "via MyApp" text to Facebook Social Plugins

Tags: facebook, plugins

With Facebook API I can create a simple "Post to my Wall" app, which adds a "via MyApp" text to every post that is published by user.

However, if a user adds a comment using [Comments Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) their post will show on their Wall without the "via MyApp" text. The same situation takes place when a user clicks on the Like Button and leaves a comment to their like.

What can be done to include the "via MyApp" text?

My code:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MYAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:comments href="http://example.com" num_posts="2" width="470"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your comment box script like the one below just replace `appId=3453534536334` with your application ID of MyApp

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=3453534536334";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work. Did you test it ?

Comment: Why should we test it?  Seriously, we're here on our own free time offering suggestions.  For mani's answer, it was an excellent guess. @Jason since you did't provide us code to look at to help debugging, we're really left here in the dark as to what it can be.  So don't bludgeon mani for trying to help.

Comment: @DMCS I'm deeply sorry for troubles. mani's post contains my whole code - it's default code from Facebook documentation. I added comment through it - still no "via MyApp" text